# Is there a way to display negative values with the case function?

Tags: mysql, date, join, average, window-functions

**Question:**

Provide a report that shows the customer’s full name (first and last name together), the cottage name, the region name of the cottage, the date of booking (in the format 15th of December, 2017), the booking price, and the difference between the booking price of that cottage and the average booking price of all cottages (truncated to the nearest 1 decimal place in the format $yy.y e.g. $25.6), arranged in descending order by full name.

**My answer:**

```
SELECT CONCAT(Customer_FName," ",Customer_LName) AS 'Name', Cottage_Name, Region_Name, 
DATE_FORMAT(Booking_Date,"%D %M %Y" ) AS 'Date Booked', Booking_Price,
CASE 
    WHEN AVG(Booking_Price) < Booking_Price THEN Booking_Price - AVG(Booking_Price)
    ELSE -1 * (AVG(Booking_Price) - Booking_Price)
END AS 'Diff From Average'

FROM Customer

JOIN Booking USING(Customer_ID)
JOIN Cottage
JOIN Region
GROUP BY Name;
```

My outputs: 
[image]

The desired output has to display negative values instead of 0's

My question: Does anyone know about a function that can do the same as the `CASE... WHEN` and display negative values?

SQLFiddle(containing the data and all necessary files): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a40db/2/0

ERD: [image]

Hint from the question:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only zero because the average are the same with the booking price

But there is no need to make your case at all

You should better use proper joins with an ON clqause

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(Customer_FName," ",Customer_LName) AS 'Name'
    , Cottage_Name
     , Region_Name, 
     DATE_FORMAT(Booking_Date,"%D %M %Y" ) AS 'Date Booked'
    , Booking_Price
    ,
    CONCAT('$',ROUND((Booking_Price - AVG(Booking_Price)),1)) AS 'Diff From Average'
FROM Customer
    JOIN Booking USING(Customer_ID)
    JOIN Cottage
   JOIN Region
GROUP BY Name;



Name            Cottage_Name                        Region_Name     Date Booked         Booking_Price   Diff From Average
Bob Perkins     Atlantic Beach Resort Cottage 1     Halifax         10th January 2018   144             $0.0
Charlie Oscar   Atlantic Beach Resort Cottage 1     Halifax         15th January 2018   1176            $294.0
Eve Evenfield   Atlantic Beach Resort Cottage 1     Halifax         22nd December 2017  654             $0.0
Frank Mitchell  Atlantic Beach Resort Cottage 1     Halifax         15th January 2018   384             $0.0
Grace Damon     Atlantic Beach Resort Cottage 1     Halifax         1st January 2018    170             $0.0
Student DalFCS  Atlantic Beach Resort Cottage 1     Halifax         15th January 2018   584             $154.5
```

Comment: The question states "the average booking price of all cottages" I am a bit confused as the question gave a hint that I will post as **edit1**

Comment: My technic in solving the question is writing something that works up to some columns and then implements some code little by little.

Comment: I changed that it fits the question. I removed the average, because i added it  to proof the answer. Now ot shows the dolar sign and rounded the result to 1 digit.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not properly aggregationg, although MySQL is lax enough to compile it.

If you are running MySQL 8.0 you can do it with window functions:

```
select
    concat(c.Customer_FName, ' ', c.Customer_LName) AS Name, 
    b.Cottage_Name, 
    r.Region_Name, 
    DATE_FORMAT(Booking_Date,"%D %M %Y" ) AS Date_Booked, 
    b.Booking_Price,
    AVG(b.Booking_Price) OVER() - Booking_Price diff_from_average
from customer c
inner join booking b using(customer_id)
inner join region r using(??)
```

In earlier versions, you can use an aggregarte query to compute the overal average:

```
select
    concat(c.Customer_FName, ' ', c.Customer_LName) AS Name, 
    b.Cottage_Name, 
    r.Region_Name, 
    date_format(Booking_Date,"%D %M %Y" ) AS Date_Booked, 
    b.Booking_Price,
    a.avg_booking_Price - Booking_Price diff_from_average
from customer c
inner join booking b using(customer_id)
inner join region r using(??)
cross join (select avg(booking_price) avg_booking_price from booking) a
```

Side notes:

- I added table aliases and attempted to prefix the columns with the relevant table - you might need to review that
- you are missing a join condition on `region`

Comment: Are aliases necessary in this kind of problem? Why does the join on Region need a condition?

Comment: Aliases are useful as soon as more that one table is involved in the query - prefixing the column makes it unambiguous from which table they come from (and avoids name clashes). As for `region`: you need a join condition that reflects the relation between `booking` and `region`, else you get a cartesian products of the rows of both tables.